# Is Bold Report and Syncfusion Community Edition Good for .NET5

Tags: asp.net, report, blazor, syncfusion

I am planning to develop ASP.NET .NET5 with Blazor webassembly as front end.

I am thinking of using report service like RLDC. I found bold report is free.

Is this really free?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contacting Bold Reports Product.

1. We can able to use the Bold Reports Report viewer in Blazor web assembly application with ASP.NET Core hosted to rendering the RDLC report and visit our below help documentation for detailed definition for your reference.
   https://help.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/javascript-reporting/report-viewer/how-to/use-javascript-reportviewer-in-blazor-web-assembly-application/#how-to-use-javascript-reportviewer-in-code-classlanguage-textblazor-web-assemblycode-app-application
2. Our Bold Reports Report Viewer SDK with Syncfusion community licensing to access our Bold Reports Report Viewer product to rendering the RDLC report. Visit our below help documentation for your reference.
   https://help.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/licensing/faq/can-the-syncfusion-community-license-be-used-with-bold-reports/

Regards,
Mahendran S.